# How to get Apex:inputfield value in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to store value in an object using:
`<apex:inputField type="number" value="{!VS.Vegetable_Amount__c}" id="v0" />`

in the controller I am doing this:

```
public Expense_Object__c VS {get;set;}
public PageReference saveAndReturn()
{
        system.debug('Value is:'+VS.Total_Amount__c);
}
```

I am trying to fetch value here but neither data is getting inserted nor I am getting any value?

Comment: Quick tip: Stackexchange sites don't render things that look like HTML (i.e. Visualforce) unless they're formatted as code (either inline code, or a code block). You should take a look at [the formatting page in the help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) so you can avoid this problem in the future. Proper formatting and indentation also makes things easier to read, and the fewer barriers you introduce between your problem and someone trying to understand it and help, the better it'll be for you.

Comment: ok @DerekF.Can anyone please hep its urgent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Expense_Object__c VS1 {get;set;}//This I was using already
public SaveAndReturnController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)//This 
is new
{
 VS = new Expense_Object__c();
 this.controller = controller;        
}
public PageReference saveAndReturn()
{ 
system.debug('X is:'+VS.Vegetable_Amount__c);
PageReference cancel = new 
PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer'));
insert VS;//introduced this insert
//controller.save(); I was using this previously so commented
return cancel;      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not much code to go on, but a quick guess: you need to create an instance of `Expense_Object__c` and assign it to `VS` in the controller's constructor. Currently, it looks like `VS` is null.

```
public with sharing class YourClassName {

    public Expense_Object__c VS {get;set;}

    public YourClassName() {
        // create an expense object instance to use
        VS = new Expense_Object__c();
    }

    public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    {
        system.debug('Value is:'+VS.Total_Amount__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok let me try and get back

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to check/correct

- You have to create an instance of  Expense_Object__c object and assign it to VS variable.
- You are using `Vegetable_Amount__c` in the input field and you are checking the value of `Total_Amount__c` in debug log.

**Note:** There is no insert statement in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Did the changes as below:  public with sharing class SaveAndReturnController {

    public Expense_Object__c VS {get;set;}

    public SaveAndReturnController() {
        VS = new Expense_Object__c();
    }

    public PageReference saveAndReturn()
    { 
        system.debug('Value  is:'+VS.Vegetable_Amount__c);
       //I am saving after this   
    }
} But getting error on preview of VF attempt to de-refernce a null object. Any suggestion?

Comment: I am able to achieve it Thank you all for the help.Let me post the Answer.